# How do I remove or disable PHP editor in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: zend-studio, aptana3

I am trying to install Aptana as an Eclipse plugin for Zend Studio because the HTML/Javascript editor  is so much better in Aptana, but I still want Zend Studio to handle PHP.  I am receiving an "Unsupported content type in editor" message when I try to edit PHP files.  It appears that Aptana is trying to take over my PHP editing.  I am not sure if the message is Aptana complaining because the Zend Studio is opening the file or Zend Studio complaining because Aptana wants the file.  Obviously, a conflict exists as if I make the Aptana editor the default for PHP or uninstall the Aptana plug in, the message goes away.

I am wondering if I can just completely disable or remove the PHP Plugin from Aptana Studio 3 and see if that solves the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like if you install Eclipse Indigo and then add the Aptana 3 addon then you go to the `Project Natures` in the project preferences you can see a few options:

```
PHP
Rails
Ruby
Web
org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature
```

Disable the first PHP option and rebuild your project. It will work. And you have the zend codeintel as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Aptana3 plugin does that. It does the same thing with PDT and it's most annoying since there Aptana plugin does other things so beautifully. It would be nice if you could elect which editor to use and have both handle PHP files just fine, but it seems that having more than one editor in Eclipse assigned to PHP causes conflicts. And unfortunately, there is no way to remove just the PHP component from the Aptana Studio plugin.

You could install the Aptana Studio 2, which does not have the PHP editor (I understand) and/or you could install the stand-alone version of Aptana Studio 3 to do the things that you want to do with it and leave the plugin out out of your Eclipse installation, but that's not so ideal, I guess. I'd also love to see a better resolution to multiple PHP editors working nicely in Eclipse (and being able to set one -- i.e., for now, not Aptana -- as primary default).

Answer (score 0):

@Lowell - It's not Aptana Studio fault ;-) Unfortunately, it's a WST issue that is opened forever and not being attended. Since PDT and Zend Studio depends on WST, this problem surface when there is another product that sets up the content-types as they should in Eclipse.

See more details at: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3185 (this one is for the CSS editor, but it's the same with other editors that share same file-extensions. See Max Stepanov's explanation on the bottom).

Removing the project natures that were contributed by Aptana is a partial workaround. You can right-click your PHP project and select Properties, navigate to the `Project Natures` item and un-check the 'PHP' nature. After that, you will be able to open the PHP files with Zend Studio's editor. However... it's only a partial workaround because you'll still need the `Zend's PHP Nature` there in order to have Zend's project management work correctly (e.g. indexing, content-assist etc.).

So... a close-to-complete workaround would be to create a PHP project using Zend PHP project wizard (not Aptana's). Then, after the project was created, follow the natures instructions above and add the Aptana's `Web` nature to enable the HTML, JS and CSS goodies.

Hope that helps...